# How to store and open files without making them recoverable?

Tags: encryption, windows-10, data-recovery

I would like to store and work with some files but simply set a password to my Windows account isn't enough as the hard drive can be removed and the files can be recovered.

I am wondering if I create an encrypted container with for example veracrypt. And open the files and then close the container after I am finished will it be possible to recover those files?

Comment: What happens if you enable Full Disk Encryption as well? This should solve the problem. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to read the [VeraCrypt documentation](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Documentation.html), particularly the sections entitled *Threat Model* and *Security Requirements and Precautions*. A software's threat model defines what it protects against and doesn't. VeraCrypt's *Security Requirements and Precautions* mentions known vulnerabilities, attacks, and how to prevent or limit their respective damage.

Your operating system will store copies of opened files in the swap file, temporary folders, lists of recently opened files, etc, so recovery can be possible depending on what OS you use and how it's configured.

Full-disk encryption solves all of those problems, but also has vulnerabilities to things like cold-boot attacks.